# Yii2 UrlManager + wrong generate route

Tags: url, parameters, module, yii2, yii-url-manager

I have some problem - urlrules is correct but generated url from yii\bootstrap\Nav not correctly ->: 
**{domain}/armory/search?server=Lorem+ipsum**
but this url working too -> **{domain}/armory/search/Lorem+ipsum**

```
'search/<server>' => 'search/index'
```

url rule ^

```
protected function addUrlManagerRules($app)
{
    $app->urlManager->addRules([new GroupUrlRule([
        'prefix' => $this->id,
        'rules' => require __DIR__ . '/url-rules.php',
    ])],true);

}
```

why this not generate url like **{domain}/armory/search/Lorem+ipsum**

```
'url' => ['/armory/search', 'server' => 'Lorem+ipsum'],
```

Comment: The posts should be written in English, so it will be useful for the other members of the community!

Comment: Not understandable text

Comment: It's Russian, So try asking your question here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ Это английский сайт, попробуйте попросить его там

Comment: translated - english so bad :C

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pattern in the format `<ParamName:RegExp>`

[Read here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#named-parameters)

try something like this in your `urlManager` section `rules`.

`'site/search/<server:\w+>' => 'site/search'`

`Url::to(['site/search', 'server' => 'lorem_ipsum'])` could be display `site/search/lorem_ipsum`